# querySelector not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to catch this class as soon as I create it, but this code ALWAYS logs out: results: null. Why is that?

```
let classname = (player == 0) ? ("computerCardholder") : ("userCardholder")
const cardholder = document.createElement("div");
    cardholder.className = classname
    d = document.querySelector(classname)
    console.log("results:   ", d)
```

Comment: You are just missing the dot infront of classname so it should be `.className`

Comment: @Aaqib classname is a variable so it needs the dot concatenated

Answer (score 3):

The CSS selector for class is `.className` you're using just `className` (you're missing the dot at the start).

Try:

```
d = document.querySelector("." + classname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ternary line should be formatted like this:

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

Remove the parentheses.

```
let classname = player === 0 ? "computerCardholder" : "userCardholder";
```

Also this line should be formatted like this:

```
d = document.querySelector("." + classname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you append the cardholder div to the body? also, why are you using the document.querySelectory when you already have a reference to it

```
let player = 0;
let className = player === 0? 'computerCardholder' : 'userCardholder';
const cardholder = document.createElement('div');
cardholder.className = className;
document.body.appendChild(cardholder);

// Why not use: d = cardholder;
let d = document.querySelector('.' + className);
console.log('results    ', d);
```